# On vue 3 v-if not working for ref value returned from composable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, composable

I created a composable with a reactive boolean. For some reason, the reactive boolean only works with `.value` in the template `v-if`. It doesn't automatically unwraps it inside the template.

But if I use a boolean ref directly on the vue component, it works. I reproduced it [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/friendly-blackwell-j2xf6g?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A23%2C47)

The code:

```
// useToggle.ts file
import { ref } from "vue";

const visible = ref(true);

export function useToggle() {
  function toggle() {
    visible.value = !visible.value;
  }

  function close() {
    visible.value = false;
  }

  return {
    visible,
    toggle,
    close,
  };
}


// App.vue file
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useToggle } from "./useToggle";

const visible = ref(true);
const t = useToggle();
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="visible = !visible">toggle local</button>
  <div v-if="visible">local</div>

  <button @click="t.toggle">toggle global without value</button>
  <div v-if="t.visible">global (this doesn't work)</div>
  <div v-if="t.visible.value">global (this doesn't work)</div>

  {{t.visible}} (but this, updates)

</template>
```

I don't understand why the v-if doesn't work the same. What can I do to make the composable work like the local ref?

Comment: Please, list useToggle for clarity, the question can become unintelligible if a demo goes offline. It's not a bad question, there's an inconsistency with interpolation syntax, it allows for additional unwrapping, the correct thing is to use {{t.visible.value}} universally, or stick to unwrapped refs by destructuring `t`

Comment: Good point, thanks for the reminder. These reproduction sites are not very stable. I couldn't find mention of this inconsistency. I suppose there is some limitation because why wouldn't it unwrap on the v-if? If it's working like this it almost seems like a bug. In any case I think I'm going to start using value by default.

Comment: Only top-level refs are expected to be unwrapped, as the answer states, it would be a bug if {{t.visible.value}} were not working, but it is, so I'd consider it an inconsistency. It makes sense to open an issue but this would be a breaking change for cases like this one

Answer (score 1):

The unwrapping only applies if the ref is a top-level property on the template render context.
And ref will also be unwrapped if it is the final evaluated value of a text interpolation.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-templates

Comment: But how is it showing true when I put `{{t.visible}}`? Shouldn't it show object in that case?

Comment: {{t.visible}} is the final evaluated value of a text interpolation in this case. But v-if="t.visible" is not.

Comment: You can fix this by putting t.visible top-level property like this const { visible } = useToggle(); in script tag.

Comment: It's still inconsistent. It also doesn't help that  "It's easy to lose reactivity when destructuring reactive objects, while it can be cumbersome to use .value everywhere when using refs". So I avoid destructuring. Link: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useToggle } from "./useToggle";

const visible = ref(true);
const {visible:v,toggle} = useToggle();
</script>

<template>
  <div>composable state: {{v }}</div>
  <div :style="{ display: 'flex' }">
    <div>
      <button @click="visible = !visible">toggle local</button>
      <div v-if="visible">local</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button @click="toggle">toggle global with value</button>
      <div v-if="v">toggle works here</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="toggle">toggle global without value</button>
      <div v-if="v">toggle broken here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import AppHeader from '@/components/header/AppHeader.vue'
import AppFooter from '@/components/AppFooter.vue'
import AppLoading from '@/components/utils/AppLoading.vue';
// import BreadCrumbs from './components/utils/BreadCrumbs.vue'
// const isReady = ref(false)
// const router = useRouter()
// router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
//  isReady.value = false;
//  setTimeout(()=> isReady.value = true)
//  next()
// })
    
</script>
    
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <div class="view z-page">
    <!-- <BreadCrumbs /> -->
    <router-view ></router-view>
    <AppLoading v-show="false"/>
  </div>
  <AppFooter />
</template>
```

after adding a `ref` to the `app.vue`, the same thing happened to me, and when I remove it it goes back to its normal state.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <AppHeader />
    <div class="view z-page">
        <!-- <BreadCrumbs /> -->
        <router-view v-show="isReady"></router-view>
        <AppLoading v-show="!isReady"/>
    </div>
    <AppFooter />
</template>
```

Yeah when i render v-show on router view and uncomment the commented it gives me back the same error